# Reloading page vs Staying in page for long duration

Tags: seo, google-adsense, google-adsense-policies, technical-seo

I have a WordPress site in which many pages content gets changing constantly.

Currently I placed a reload button on the page so user can click several times to reload the entire page to see the new updated content.

I want to know whether its a good practice of making the user to reload the page or Can I make the pages to update the content dynamically (Realtime) without reloading the page? So users no need to refresh the webpage to see the new content.

Will any of this method creates positive/negative impact on SEO and Google AdSense?

Comment: @john Conde - Hope you the best person to answer this question.

Comment: Making the user reload the page is not a great look.  Updating the page can be done (among other ways)  in AJAX - Start at https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp  - https://whitefoxcreative.com/developers/ajax/refresh-a-section-of-a-page-at-specific-intervals-using-ajax/ also seems to be a good starting place

Answer (score 1):

This seems more like a UX concern to me, which would be up to you do decide.

From an SEO perspective, Google is going to crawl pages as they exist when the page loads. The information about your pages that Googlebot gathers when it crawls your pages will be used to index, and decide how to rank them.

Nothing new there for you. SEO shouldn't be a problem.

Think about UX and whether or not your configuration plays nice with AdSense.